# Integral problem involving derangements and improper integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, derangements

I am curious to see how to solve the following problem:

> Let
> $$I(n)=\int_0^{\infty}(t-1)^ne^{-t}dt$$
> If $D(n)$ is the number of derangements of $n$, then what is $I(42)-D(42)$.

This problem is found on the bottom of this page: https://brilliant.org/wiki/derangements/

I know
\begin{align*}I(42)&=\int_0^{\infty}(t-1)^{42}e^{-t}dt,\\
D(42)&=42!\sum_{k=0}^{42}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!},\\
e^x&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!},\end{align*}
but I am not sure how to connect these pieces together. Any suggestions?

Comment: We have [$I(n)=D(n)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Generalizations).

Comment: Personally, I would first use the substitution $~u = (t-1) \implies t = u+1, ~du = dt.~$  This transforms the indefinite integral $~\displaystyle \int (t-1)^n ~e^{-t} ~dt ~$ into the integral $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{e} \times \int ~u^n ~e^{-u} ~du. ~$  Then, you can use integration by parts to develop the recursion formula $$\int ~u^n ~e^{-u} ~du = -\left( ~u^n ~e^{-u} ~\right) + \left( n \times \int ~u^{n-1} ~e^{-u} ~du ~\right).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
I(n) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(t-1\right)^{n}e^{-t}dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}t^{n-k}\left(-1\right)^{k}e^{-t}dt \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n-k}e^{-t}dt \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}(n-k)! \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(-1\right)^{k}(n-k)! \\
&= n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k!} \\
&= D(n) \\
\end{align}
$$

Which implies that $I(n) - D(n) = 0$. Let $n=42$ and we are done.